# systemd socket with "Accept=true" has long delay before service is launched

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, systemd

I have a systemd .socket paired with an @.service.  The socket contains "Accept=yes" in order to accept a TCP connection from a client over the specified port, after which an @.service instance is created which executes my server program to handle the TCP connection.  Currently, I am testing with one client (Windows software) connecting to the server (linux c++).

My problem is that for the first client connection attempt, the TCP connection succeeds but there is a long delay (5-10 seconds) before systemd launches the associated @.service.  Any subsequent connections will launch the @.service almost immediately, **UNLESS a TCP RST packet is received**.  If a TCP RST packet is received, the next connection again as a 5-10 second delay before the @.service is launched, and the cycle repeats itself.

My .socket file is very simple.  For the [Socket] portion, it really just specifies a ListenStream port and Accept=true.

Any ideas what may be causing this delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that is coming to my mind is that systemd itself is not getting enough CPU to accept the connection but maybe that is not what it is since you think it has something to do with TCP RST packet.

You can change the log level to debug on /etc/systemd/system.conf and have more information about when systemd actually accepts the connection.

The way it works is, systemd listens the socket on .socket file and puts an epoll on the file descriptor. As soon as there is an activity on the socket, systemd gets notification in its event loop. Then it accepts the connection and starts the program specified in .service file.

Comment: Changing the log level definitely helps see more info related to the timing.  What's weird is I changed my code for the client to require a "ready" tcp packet from the server before initiating an SSL connection (in an attempt to account for the systemd delay in launching the server), and ever since I haven't been able to recreate this delay.  But your information helped confirm how systemd works with the socket and will help me debug if I can get this to occur again, so thank you.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It's not even an answer.